# AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm novice in python, and I couldn't understand how to correctly formatting dates.

My data is like this `Fri, 09 Dec 2011 06:50:37 UTC`

I'm preparing it like this:

```
dates.append(time.strptime(row[5], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
```

Then I'm trying to use it

```
dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)
```

get following error:

```
AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `time` module, but `matplotlib` expects the `datetime` object.

Try using something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dates.append(datetime.strptime(row[5], "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"))
...
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but now, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: I've just changed order of imports to 
`from pylab import *
from datetime import datetime`
and it works! Thanks!