# Why do I get an AttributeError when I use scatter() but not when I use plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-datetime

I wish to plot using Matplotlib/pylab and show date and time on the `x-axis`. For this, I'm using the datetime module.

Here is a working code that does exactly what is required-

```
import datetime
from pylab import *

figure()
t2=[]
t2.append(datetime.datetime(1970,1,1))
t2.append(datetime.datetime(2000,1,1))
xend= datetime.datetime.now()
yy=['0', '1']
plot(t2, yy)
print "lim is", xend
xlim(datetime.datetime(1980,1,1), xend)
```

However, when I use the `scatter(t2,yy)` command instead of `plot (t2,yy)`, it gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.string_' object has no attribute 'toordinal'

Why is this happening and how can I show a scatter along with plot?

A similar question has been asked before as-
[AttributeError: 'time.struct_time' object has no attribute 'toordinal'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538296/attributeerror-time-struct-time-object-has-no-attribute-toordinal)
but the solutions don't help.

Comment: what do you wish to accomplish with `scatter` that `plot` can't handle? I ask b/c conceptually, I don't think that scatter is appropriate for a time series -- but that's a pretty arbitrary distinction even in my own mind.

Comment: 'plot' shows me a line interconnecting all data points, but not the data points themselves (unless there's a way I don't know of). But I want to also display the data points so that the viewer knows at which points in time the data was collected.

Comment: On an unrelated note, how do you show code inline in stack overflow? Like what you did above with the words scatter and plot.

Comment: For the first question, do `plot(x, y, 'ko')` and you'll just get black dots. For the second, use backticks: "`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `int` or `float` type for `yy` you don't get this error with `scatter()`:

```
yy = [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extended example of how I would do this:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t2=[
    datetime.datetime(1970,1,1),
    datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)
]
xend = datetime.datetime.now()
yy= [0, 1]
ax.plot(t2, yy, linestyle='none', marker='s', 
        markerfacecolor='cornflowerblue', 
        markeredgecolor='black',
        markersize=7,
        label='my scatter plot')

print("lim is {0}".format(xend))
ax.set_xlim(left=datetime.datetime(1960,1,1), right=xend)
ax.set_ylim(bottom=-1, top=2)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Value')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image]